# Reload meta http-equiv charset after ajax page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, character-encoding

On my site I use a fair amount of special characters like © etc...

Now, Jquery messes up these special characters unless you specify the proper charset, in this case -

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1" />
```

The problem i'm having is that after using ajaxify to load the main chunk of the content on my site this tag isn't being reloaded. So the first time you load the page the correct characters are displayed then as soon as you use ajax to load a new page they all turn into that lovely little black box question mark that JQuery loves to spit out.

So my question...

How can I force that meta tag to reload after each new page is loaded with Ajaxify.js?

Comment: UTF-8 should handle all those charsets, which should fix that issue.

Comment: Actually we should finally say "bye" to all other than UTF-8 :) an hopefully one day we'll not even have to mention the charset at all. But that's one day... :D

Comment: Nope, tried that, same thing happening.

Comment: @grant have you tried to save your document, the one you're pulling in - or even both of them (under: **Encoding**) as **UTF-8 Without BOM**?

Comment: @Roko You might as well be speaking a different language there my friend! haha, can you explain what you mean please? How would I do that?

Comment: @Grant - your document might be saved with a wrong encoding. Save them as UTF-8 (In Notepad++ use **Without BOM** under the "Encoding" menu) Also, make sure to use: `<meta charset=utf-8 />`

Comment: Mac based here so no notepad. I did just read that UTF-8 replaces the © symbol and lots of other useful ones with the diamond question mark which is no good for me so I'll have to stick with ISO-8859-1.

Comment: And now I've just read that the person that made that statement about UTF-8 was completely wrong.. lol god bless the Stack ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself...

In your .htaccess file add the following line

```
AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1
```

That fixes it.